# Web3 works on mainnet, not on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have an identical contract on the Mainnet and Ropsten. Both work fine in Remix. Using a python program on my Windows machine, I find that I get an error accessing the Ropsten contract, but not the mainnet version. All I changed in my Python program was the contract address and provider URL:
"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/3e4616a1aed64da3b29e20c2970e23b7"
to
"https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3e4616a1aed64da3b29e20c2970e23b7"

The flawed program generates an error on the first contract call

```
currDay = contract.functions.currentDay().call()
```

This generates a scalar output, type uint8. The error I get is:

```
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call currentDay return data b'' for output_types ['uint8']
```

As mentioned, this works fine for the mainnet, and also works fine within Remix for both the Ropsten and Mainnet contracts.

Answer (score 0):

The contract address will be different on different networks. This is why the call fails.

Comment: As mentioned, I changed the contract address. The contract is identical, just one on Ropsten, one on the Mainnet. I then only changed the contract address and the provider URL to account for the difference. I suppose there's something in the python Web3 or HTTPProvider packages.

Comment: Looks like I was right :)

Answer (score 0):

My bad: My program pulled in the Mainnet contract address from the json. This overwrote the correct address I posted above it. I forgot I had that address definition buried there, as it's redundant.